# Does sourceforge.net have a search API?

Tags: api, sourceforge

Does sourceforge.net offer an API of any sort for accessing their data base programmatically, e.g. for searching all projects that use a certain programming language?

Answer (score 1):

SourceForge.Net currently doesn't have a search API that returns a  list of projects based on trove data.

For more information on what SourceForge.Net has regarding an API see [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/API) and for more information on Trove see [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Software%20Map%20and%20Trove)